# c# string.format removing my quot marks

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

I don't know if i can't read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) or need to drink another cup of coffee.

I would like to format a decimal into some html. The following code works in that it formats the string however it strips any type of quotation or apostrophe mark added.

```
private string FormatOutput1 = "{0:<span style='font-size: 14px;'>$0</span>.00}";
private string FormatOutput2 = "{0:<span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">$0</span>.00}";
private string FormatOutput3 = @"{0:<span style=""font-size: 14px;"">$0</span>.00}";
private string FormatOutput3 = "{0:<span style=\'font-size: 14px;\'>$0</span>.00}";
string.Format( FormatOutput, order.OrderTotal ) );
```

to me always results in (assuming the decimal is 330)

```
<span style=font-size: 14px;>$330</span>.00
```

the lack of quotation marks is breaking the desired output. Is there a way around this or something that I am missing.

Comment: Why are you including all the markup in the format string? That seems like a bad approach to me and might be screwing up the format string for `String.Format()`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `format = @"<span style=\"...\">$</span>{0:0.000}";` and placing the markup before the place holder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really just want to format the decimal then move the html before the curly brackets:

```
string FormatOutput = "<span style='font-size: 14px;'>$</span>{0:0.00}";
```

To accomodate the update, you can escape it with `\` but since it is a string, you need to use two `\\` and also escape the `;`:

```
string FormatOutput = "{0:<span style=\\'font-size: 14px\\;\\'>0</span>.00}";
```

Comment: Yep, Op is reading the manual wrong I think.  You might want to un-escape the single-quotes though.

Comment: sorry my code sample was incorrect. I have updated it and the output